# Referring R to a person

Tags: letters

How can R refer to a person only by adding a symbol?

Conditions:

1. You cannot add any letter with R.
2. You can add only one symbol.

(EXPLANATION IS NECCESSARY)

Comment: Is "any letter" limited to the Latin alphabet?

Comment: It can be of any language.

Comment: The difference between "symbol" and "letter" (in any language) is very vague and might lead to many equally "valid" solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

> .R (dot-r)

Which would become a rebus for

> daughter

Comment: Kinda British solution.

Comment: @Mordechai.  I agree; probably should have had an english tag on it.

Answer (score 8):

How about

> **R&**

which refers to

> me!

Comment: How it refers to 'me'?

Comment: @IQWANTER Me, because I'm Rand.

Answer (score 6):

It could be

> `へR`. That is the Japanese katakana for "he", making the phrase "her" (which refers to a person). Similarly, it could *also* be:
>
>  `Rユ` (Ryu (name): katakana 'yu')
>  `Ræ` (Rae (name): "ash", letter in Danish and Norwegian, among others)
>  `Rໃ` (Ray (name): Lao vowel sign 'ay')
>  `Rᢰ` (Roy (name): Canadian syllabics 'oy')
>  `Rꀓ` (Rex (name): Yi syllable 'ex')
>  `R` (Ron (name): Shavian letter 'on')
>  `ᓯR` (Sir: Canadian syllabics 'si')
>  `*R` (Starr (last name of a Beatles drummer): asterisk)
>  `R&` (Ayn Rand or Rand al'Thor, as stated in other answers)

All of these are symbols in some language.

Comment: however, "You cannot add any letter" and many of these symbols are letters.

Comment: @RadovanGarabíkOnly æ and  are letters; the others are characters in syllabaries or abugidas, scripts that don't have letters.

Comment: that's... debatable, but I guess could be conceded for the purpose of the puzzle :-)

Answer (score 5):

> R@

[Dictionary.com Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rat?s=t):

> rat: a person who abandons or betrays his or her party or associates, especially in a time of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

How about

> **R￥**
> R(Ar) + ￥(Yen)
>  
> Which is likely to pronounce [Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan) (A member of the ancient Aryan people)

Answer (score 3):

Using the same logic as Kyle:

> R& for writer Ayn Rand.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. R. (adding a dot/period/full stop). This [initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#After_initials) refers, obviously, to someone whose name starts with R (e.g. yours truly).

> 2. R2. This refers (e.g. affectionately) to [R2-D2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2), if we consider him/her/it a person (I would!).

> 3. R: Used to denote direct speech by someone whose name starts with R (can be argued to be a special case of 1., where the period is dropped)

Comment: "yours truly" doesn't start with R; it starts with Y! :-P

Answer (score 2):

It's common to refer to people in an online chat (or even in comments here on Stack Exchange) by preceding it with a specific non-letter symbol, like so:

> @R